# Why am I getting seg fault (core dumped) with this?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So I am trying to write a binary search tree and this erase function gives me a seg fault. My Node class has a temp data, and pointer to a left & right child node along with a parent node.
I have a function find(temp key) that returns a node* to the Node that holds key as its data. So in my main, I have

```
Node<temp>* p = bTree->find(key);
```

The find function works, but then when I do
bTree->erase(p);
and print my result, iit compiles but i get a seg fault. Please help, Thank you.

```
template <typename temp>
void BinTree<temp>::erase(Node<temp>* n){

  if(!n->lChild && !n->rChild){ //n has no children
    delete n;
    n = nullptr;
  }

  else if(n->lChild && n->rChild){ //n has two children
    Node<temp>* p = n->rChild;
    while(p->lChild)
        p = p->lChild; //p will be n's successor
    n->data = p->data; //set the data to that of the successor
    if(p->rChild){  //take care of p's right child if it has one
        p->parent->lChild = p->rChild;
        p->rChild->parent = p->parent;
    }
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
  }

  else{ //n only has one child
    if(n->parent){
        if(n->data < n->parent->data){ //n is a left child
            if(n->lChild){ //n has only a left child
                n->lChild->parent = n->parent;
                n->parent->lChild = n->lChild;
            }
            else{ //n has only a right child
                n->rChild->parent = n->parent;
                n->parent->lChild = n->rChild;
            }
        }
        else{ //n is a right child
            if(n->lChild){ //n has only a left child
                n->lChild->parent = n->parent;
                n->parent->rChild = n->lChild;
            }
            else{ //n has only a right child
                n->rChild->parent = n->parent;
                n->parent->rChild = n->rChild;
            }
        }
    }
    else{ //n is  the root and has no parent, but still only has one child
        if(n->lChild)
            root = n->lChild;
        else
            root = n->rChild;
    }
    delete n;
    n = nullptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the program?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1):

You got some serious misunderstanding of pointers.

What matters is not only the node itself that you are deleting, but what other pointers are pointing to the node.

For example, take a look at your first case in erase():

```
if(!n->lChild && !n->rChild){ //n has no children
  delete n;
  n = nullptr;
}
```

You delete node n. But the parent of n still stores a pointer to n....

Comment: Don't mind that last comment. I didn't even think about it. Thank you for your help

Comment: A pointer is just an 8-byte number like a long integer. If parent->left stores the address of a node and you set another pointer n = parent->left, then the same 8-byte memory address of the node is stored in two places -- once in the 'left' field of the parent node and the second time in your temporary variable n. Now if you "delete n;", the value stored at variable n AND parent->left are still the old (now invalid) address, NOT nullptr.